web video server over HTTPS
I'm on ROS 2 Humble and my web app is on https. Is there any way I can make web_video_server stream the image topics over https/ssl instead of http so i can use them inside my https web app?
This is how I use web_video_server inside my web app:
<mat-tab-group> <mat-tab label="RGB Camera"> <img class="img-fluid" [style.width.px]="getWidthOfDiv()" [style.height.px]="getWidthOfDiv()/2" src="http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/stereo/left/image_rect_color_out1_high">  </mat-tab> <mat-tab label="Depth Camera"> <img class="img-fluid" [style.width.px]="getWidthOfDiv()" [style.height.px]="getWidthOfDiv()/2" src="http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/stereo/depth"> </mat-tab> </mat-tab-group>
I can't find any useful resources to help me make this happen, I've opened an issue on GitHub but the repo seems to be dead. Is this possible at all? Is there any alternative that streams image topics over HTTPS that you've worked with and recommend? Thanks in advance!

You could host the web_video_server behind a reverse proxy such as Nginx to handle the SSL termination. There is a tutorial here.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
